# Framework for analyzing transaction history

Tags: python, modeling, performanceanalytics, data-mining

After many years of being discretionary trader I'm finally moving to systematized trading.

I have all the transaction history from my broker I want to be the basis of my models.
Is there a framework I can use that will process this data and provide me with some  insights? (preferably in Python)

Thank you

Comment: `pyfolio` (https://github.com/quantopian/pyfolio) is popular. `bt` (https://pmorissette.github.io/bt/) has some good utilities too.

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41345/is-there-a-python-library-to-generate-performance-metrics-from-returns-of-the-st/41359#41359